# How to make all fields readonly in form view odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10

I was trying to make all fields in a form view read-only in odoov10. Is there any python method through I can get all the form view fields and change its attribute to readonly="True"?

Comment: Hi Bro, in this case give or edit the access right of models from `ir.security`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's a correct method, but there is a workaroud you can use:

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(Lead, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    if view_type == 'form':
        res['arch'] = self.fields_view_get_address(res['arch'])
        # res contains the view form, and you can manipulate res string, as you desired.
    return res
```

Alternatively you can disable edit option in the form view, by using:

```
<field ... edit="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>` to the `ir.model.access` record for your current model. This is an example:

```xml
<record id="access_stock_return_picking_group_stock_manager" model="ir.model.access">
    <field name="name">Permission Name</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_stock_return_picking"/>
    <field name="group_id" ref="stock.group_stock_manager"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
    <field name="active" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

For more information check the [**Odoo Documentation - Access Control**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/security.html)

Answer (score 0):

On Odoo 12 it works only by setting readonly="True" (<- CamelCase). Using edit="False" nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

```
I did like this - 
    <record id="hr_expense_inehrited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">name</field>
            <field name="model">hr.expense</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" 
     ref="expense_extended.hr_expense_form_view1"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/div/h1/field[@name='name']" 
     position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute>
                </xpath>

            </field>
        </record>
```